# mysql ERROR 2002 HY00

Tags: mysql, windows, bash, terminal, command-prompt

I am running a bash script from linux terminal on my windows command prompt and I tried installing and running MySQL but got the following error:

```
C:\Users\rfasc>bash
ryryfasch@LAPTOP-9TPB1OJ6:/mnt/c/Users/rfasc$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket ' 
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I have tried looking at othe answers from stack overflow with no luck.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql` command is looking to connect to `localhost` by default. It does this by looking for the localhost's socket information from the the [socket file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types#Socket) `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`. Right now, the `mysql` command can't find that file.

I would do the following:

- Make sure MySQL ***SERVER*** is actually installed (this is `mysqld`)
- Try to invoke `mysql` with the host flag: `mysql -h 127.0.0.1` (this tries to connect to localhost, but doesn't use the socket file).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error when attempt to connect to the MySQL server running as a service in Windows 10 through the Windows 10 Bash environment.

The issue is since MySQL is not running in the Bash environment a .sock is not being created.

Adding -h 127.0.0.1 is one way to connect from the command line but it's easier to modify the MySQL client config. To do so find where your my.cnf file is located by using the following command:

> mysql --help | grep "Default options" -A 1

That will return something similar to this:

> Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
>   /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

Track down which file your system is using. If none them exist create the file in one of the locations listed using the command:

> sudo touch /etc/my.cnf

Once you have created the file (or if you already had one) edit the my.cnf file and add the following:

> [client]
>   protocol=tcp

If you had to create the my.cnf file then just add both lines.

Then whenever you use the mysql command it will connect using tcp
instead of the sock.